# trying to get products to agree on crate versions

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to add a crate to an existing project

They share the need for a common crate (ratatui)

Originally the crate I want to add to says

`ratatui = { version = "0.21", default-features = false, features = ['crossterm', 'serde']}`

The crate I want to add says

`ratatui = { version = ">=0.23.0, <1", default-features = false, optional = true }`

So I change the original to say

`ratatui = { version = "0.23", default-features = false, features = ['crossterm', 'serde']}`

and build

My expectation is that we all end up using 0.23

What actually happens is that the original uses 0.23 but the added crate uses 0.24. This fails to work as the two are incompatible (they are passing arguments of ratatui types back and forth)

I do not own the master project, I am just putting together a PR to add a new feature

Comment: I think you've got the following bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9029 (which I also had with https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10733)

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to know that Cargo uses the first non-zero version number as the major version. So `0.23.0` and `0.24.0` are considered not compatible, while `1.23.0` and `1.24.0` are compatible.

If your goal is to just enable the features, then you can use the same exact version specifier.

```ini
ratatui = { version = ">=0.23.0, <1", default-features = false, features = ['crossterm', 'serde']}
```

If your goal is to restrict ratatui to `0.23` because you need functionality from that specific version, you should be able to use `cargo update` to revert them both to `0.23`. However, this only works for the current lockfile, so if someone depends on your crate or otherwise generates a new lockfile, it will break again.

You may also be able to [patch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) the other crate to use a different version of ratatui.

There's a few more social solutions:

- If the other crate breaks in `0.24`, ask the maintainer of the other crate to choose a specific version of ratatui.
- If all you need are the features enabled, ask the maintainer to provide features for ratatui's features.
- If you need to use something from ratatui, ask the maintainer to reexport ratatui.

Comment: "0.23.0 and 0.24.0 are considered not compatible", yes but I asked for 0.23 in one and anything >=0.23 in the other, so why not choose 0.23

Comment: @pm100 your question's comment has a github issue for this, but it's not apparent if it's intended or a bug, so there isn't an answer to that question. Currently, Cargo doesn't do it and that's all we know. You didn't really ask a question, but I was answering "how do I ensure the versions are the same?" which is actionable without knowing the intention of Cargo.